# Do the applications developed with Asp.net 1.1 run on new browsers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

I have a question about applications developed with older versions of **Asp.net** like **Asp.Net 1.1** for example.

I would like to know if an application developed with an old version of **Asp.Net** like **Asp.Net 1.1** can run properly on new browsers such as **Microsoft Edge**, **Chrome**, **chromium** ... etc?.

Are there any compatibility issues for example?

thank you for the answer

Comment: They generate truly horrific HTML and JS, but that should still work somewhat. Whether you want to is another question. Why don't you just run the application and test it using different browsers?

Comment: It depends on how the application had been coded. For example if you had followed the rules of html then that should be ok in most cases. But back in the days some people did not care about the standards. For example html used to work even without proper closing tags.

Comment: ASP.NET v2 had some issues with "newer" browsers like IE10 and Firefox 5, but there was a hotfix released for that: [Bug and Fix: ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack is undefined JavaScript error or maintain FF5 scrollbar position - Scott Hanselman's Blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/bug-and-fix-aspnet-fails-to-detect-ie10-causing-dopostback-is-undefined-javascript-error-or-maintain-ff5-scrollbar-position)

Comment: In my understanding Asp.net 1.1 generates code Html and javascript using different javascript engine and Html enjine, so the code HTML and javascript generated in Asp.net 1.1 is intended to internet explorer. the new browsers no like Edge , Chrome uses different javascript and Html engine. that's why is think that the code generated with Asp.net 1.1 will not work properly because the used engines are different, that's why i asked this question